# Inserting integer into array using 1 for loop

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to write a method that takes a sorted array and an integer, and returns a new sorted array with the integer in the correct place.

I am trying to do this without using dynamic arrays, as well as only using 1 for loop - I have this working using a different method.

This is the method :

```
public static int[] insert(int[] a, int k) {
    int j = 0;
    int[] s = new int[a.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(k < a[i] && j == 0) {
            s[i] = k;
            j++;
        } else {
            s[i + j] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

My test input is

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8};
```

and I am trying to insert a 5.

The issue I am having with this particular method is that it will always set the index after the inserted integer to 0. In this case it would store and print

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8
```

rather than

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Thanks

Comment: how it will print 4 there is no 4 in your `array1`? and inserting 5 which is already present in your `array1`.

Comment: You don't want an 'else'.

Comment: The are some handy functions in [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) that could help

Comment: @matt YOU'RE RIGHT! THANK YOU

Comment: just add `s[i + j]=a[i];` inside your `if` after `j++` to copy the value at inserted position . or simply remove `else` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not setting the index to zero, it's just jumping over one index. When `k < a[i]` is true it's incrementing `i` (in the for loop) and `j` (in `j++` statement). So when you next do `s[i + j] = a[i]` it will have skipped two positions rather than one.

The solution is to ensure that in every iteration of the loop a value from the original array is copied. In other words, once you've assigned `k` to `s[i]` you then need to assign `a[i]` to `s[i + 1]`. The simplest way to achieve this is to remove your `else` clause and execute `s[i + j]` every iteration.

Comment: You're right, any idea on how to make it only skip 1 index then? I tried s[i] = a[i] before, and obviously I just end up with duplicates of my insert.

Comment: yep I'll put some hints in the answer

Comment: turns out the 'else' was causing the skip, hmm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an alternative. Instead of using a loop, use the Arrays object to add and sort your array.

Example:

```
public int[] insert(int[] a, int k) {
    // create a copy of int array parameter and add one to the length
    int[] s = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);

    // add the second parameter at the end of the new array
    s[s.length - 1] = k;

    // sort the array
    Arrays.sort(s);

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static int[] insertIntoSortedArray(int[] array, int k) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];
    int i = 0;// for array
    int j = 0;// for new array
    boolean inserted = false;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (!inserted && k < array[i]) {
            newArray[j] = k;
            inserted = true;
        } else {
            newArray[j] = array[i++];
        }
        j++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```